# Как запустить сервис с помощью GitLab CI runner и предотвратить его остановку?

Tags: gitlab, spring-boot, gitlab-runner

Есть приложение Spring Boot, собираемое в исполняемый `.war` архив. Есть сервер GitLab CI, с помощью которого я хочу запустить тесты и выполнить деплой приложения, в случае успешно пройденных тестов.

Используется следующий конфиг для CI:

```
stages:
  - build_and_test
  - deploy

web_server_build_and_test:
  stage: build_and_test
  script:
    - mvn clean package

web_server_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn clean package -Pprod
    - service gitlab-runner-test stop
    - cp target/*.war /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
    - chmod +x /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
    - service gitlab-runner-test start
```

Выхлоп стадии `web_server_deploy` следующий:

```
$ service gitlab-runner-test stop
Stopped [13247]
$ cp target/*.war /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
$ chmod +x /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
$ service gitlab-runner-test start
Started [21177]
```

Однако, после того как runner завершил работу, процесс сервиса прибивается:

```
$ service gitlab-runner-test status
Not running (process 21177 not found)
```

Скрипт сервиса просто устанавливает переменные окружения и делегирует всю работу собранному `.war`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
export MODE=service
export APP_NAME=gitlab-runner-test
export PID_FOLDER=/var/run/gitlab-runner-test


/var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war $*
```

Когда я запускаю сервис руками (`service gitlab-runner-test start`), то он продолжает работу даже после того, как я выхожу из под пользователя.

Есть вероятность, что я неправильно настроил сервис, но как его починить - не представляю.

Конфигурация:

1. Ubuntu 14.04
2. Gitlab CI multi runner version 1.0.1 (cffb5c7)

Если вы нашли проблему, то можете продублировать ответ на [англоязычную версию вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088983/how-to-start-a-service-using-gitlab-runner-and-prevent-it-from-stopping) - баунти уже ждет своего героя.

Comment: у вас варник запускается сам по себе? возможно, я чего-то не знаю, но запуск war/jar должен производиться jvm, и команда должна выглядеть как минимум как `java -jar /var/gitlab-runner-test/hitlab-runner-test.war`

Comment: Да, сам по себе. В нем лежит вот этот [скрипт](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script). Предлгаете запустить через java?

Comment: Похоже, что внутри скрипта он [запускается через `java -jar`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script#L130)

Comment: да, само нахождение скрипта в нем не поможет. war - это архив, и для его запуска линуксу нужно вообще понять, что его нужно разархивировать. сам по себе предоставленный скрипт является shell-скриптом, который может помочь запустить какой-то варник, но изнутри он этого сделать не может.

Comment: Но почему тогда я могу запустить его руками (т.е. `/var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war start`)? И он нормально стартует.

Comment: Этот скприт зашит в варник, он будет виден, если попытаться открыть  архив с помощью редактора. Таким образом, когда мы его стартуем, то система воспринимает его как обычный скрипт, который, зная свое местоположение, запускает себя с помощью `java -jar`. Я выше кидал ссылку на строку формирования команды для запуска.

Comment: Не знал, что его можно сшить, как рарджипег. Возможно, дело в окружении скрипта, который пытается его запустить (например, отстутствует JAVA_HOME)

Comment: Нет, `JAVA_HOME` точно есть, в вопросе приведен скрипт, который устанавливает переменные окружения и стартует сервис. Кроме того, если я добавлю паузу в скрипт для CI, то сервис останется жить на время этой паузы, т.е. он стартует, но почему-то runner его прибивает после завершения работы. Как отловить и предотвратить причину прибития - не знаю.

Comment: Постараюсь на выходных поднять гитлаб и поиграться